# Retrying a list of failed Tasks

Tags: c#, task

I'm trying to create a function that handles the retry logic for a list of Tasks when not all of the Tasks pass. The function currently looks as follows:

```
private async Task<List<T>> CompleteOperationsWithRetry<T>(List<Task> toComplete, int maxRetries)
{
    var completedTasks = new List<Task>();
    var failedTasks = new List<Task>();

    await Task.WhenAll(toComplete.ToArray());
    foreach (var task in toComplete)
    {
        // if task didn't complete add to failed list
        if (!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            failedTasks.Add(task);
            continue;
        }
        // add task to appropriate list depending on whether or not failed
        var list = task.IsFaulted ? failedTasks : completedTasks;
        list.Add(task);        
    }
    toComplete = failedTasks;

   // Desired: repeat code above while toComplete is not empty


   // ... eventually return completed tasks
   return completedTasks;
}
```

I want to iterate through `toComplete` and add any failed Tasks to the `failedTasks` list, which I then want to be able to re-run with a function call similar to `Task.WhenAll()` again. However, I read that once a Task is in a completed state, it can't be re-run. How can I create a new Task from an existing  failed Task so that I can re-run it?

Comment: You want to save the list of delegates that run as part of those tasks and then reassign them to new `Task` objects.

Answer (score 0):

`Task` doesn't actually know how it got started. It's just an object that holds the completion state of *something*.

That "something" isn't necessarily a background task that you started by passing a delegate to `Task.Run`. It could be something else entirely. You can create arbitrary `Task` instances and control when they get flagged as completed/faulted/canceled (see [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx)).

So there's no way to do this with `Task`s alone. You'll have to create your own object that knows how to start each task, and pass that in, and ask it to restart itself.